# Searching a vector for all instances of its first argument, then returning those in a vector

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, vector

This is indeed an assignment, but I am stuck, it may just be the wording that I am not getting.

Make a function with variable number of arguments that searches the rest of the arguments for a sub-string provided as the first argument. This function will return a vector containing all arguments that contain the sub-string

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> search(string str, ...);

int main (){
    va_list arguments;
    char contin = 'y';
    string str;

    va_start(arguments, str);
    cout << "Enter a string that will be searched for in the rest of the strings: ";
    str += va_arg(arguments, str);
    while(contin == 'y'){
        cout << "Enter a string that will be searched in: ";
        str += va_arg(arguments, str);
        cout << endl << "Enter \''y\'' to continue or \''n\'' to end to start seach:" << endl;
        cin >> contin;
    }
    va_end(arguments);
    search(arguments);
  return 0;
}

vector<string> search(string str, ... ){
    va_list containing;
    va_start (containing, str);
    if (std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), str.front()) != str.end()){
        str += va_arg(containing, str);
    }

    return containing;
}
```

I get these errors:
Line 37: "str += va_arg(containing, str);" -error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Line 40: "return containing;" - error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(const std::vector<_Ty> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'va_list' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'

Line 36: "if (std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), str.front()) != str.end()){" - error C2039: 'front' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'

Line 21/24: "str += va_arg(arguments, str);" - error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Also, am I headed in the right direction or doing something completely wrong?

Comment: +1 for a very novel use of `va_args`. Here's a man who doesn't play by anyone's rules.

Comment: va_args macros (va_list, va_start, va_end) are readonly. You can't write to it, as you do in `main`

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely things you don't understand about functions with variable args.

Firstly to call a function with variable args you just use the normal method

```
search("here", "are", "some", "strings");
```

Secondly because the types of parameters to a variable arg function are unknown you are seriously restricted in the type of values you can call the function with. Any complex object like `std::string` is forbidden. Simple types like `int`, `double` and `char *` are OK.

Thirdly the second argument to the `va_arg` macro is the type of the value you wish to access e.g. `va_arg(containing, char*)`.

I can only think that 'strings' in your assigment means the old-fashioned C type, i.e. `const char *` not `std::string`.

Comment: You are right, I don't understand a lot because my teacher thinks that reading the textbook is a good idea, and only lecture on the book compared to having actually do programs and ask questions on them to learn by doing, rather we listen and do nothing.  Thanks though, I'll see what I can do with this.